# I would like to change Button TextColor in RecyclerView

Tags: android, button, android-recyclerview, textcolor

I would like to change the color when I click the Button in RecyclerView.

I want to change the text color of the 4 button when I click the button corresponding to position 4 of position 1, 2, 3, 4.

```
public class SingleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SingleAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position);
    void onLongItemClick(int position);
}

Context context;
List<SingleItem> items;
public static OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;


public SingleAdapter(Context context, List<SingleItem> items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener)
{
    this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    SingleItem item = items.get(position);
    viewHolder.btnItemButton.setText(item.getmSubText());
}


static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

    Button btnItemButton;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        btnItemButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemButton);

        btnItemButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(onItemClickListener != null)
        {
            onItemClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

```
public class SingleItem {

String mSubText;

public SingleItem(String mSubText)
{
    this.mSubText = mSubText;
}

public String getmSubText() {
    return mSubText;
}

public void setmSubText(String mSubText)
{
    this.mSubText = mSubText;
}
```

}

```
static String mAddListDepthUnits[] = { "m", "ft", "fm", "HR", "pb" };



private void setDepthRecycler()
{
    singleItems = new ArrayList<>();
    for( int i = 0; i < mAddListDepthUnits.length; i++)
    {
        singleItems.add(new SingleItem(mAddListDepthUnits[i]));
    }

    mSingleAdapter = new fec.fishfinderapp.menu.SingleAdapter(mSubMenu_Units.getContext(), singleItems);
    midDepthRecycler.setAdapter(mSingleAdapter);

    mSingleAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new SingleAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position) {
            switch(position)
            {
                case 0 :
                case 1 :
                case 2 :
                case 3 :
                case 4 :
                case 5 :
                    break;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onLongItemClick(int position) {

        }
    });
}
```

The current code is in this state.
How can I change the text color of a specific button here?
I can hardly find the answer.
Please help me

Comment: you can pass not only `int position` of the item, but also the button itself to the listener, and in `switch(position)` change it's text color

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko What does that mean?

Comment: Create an interface similar to `OnItemClickListener`, but having also the `View` as the 2nd parameter, not only clicked position, and pass the clicked button into it. along with position. Or simply in `onClick(View v) {` in your `ViewHolder` set  the button color

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Um ... I used to do that but it did not work ...

Comment: probably you did something wrong

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko You can do btnItemButton.setTextColor () in onClick (View v), right? If so, does it change by position?

Comment: when you do `btnItemButton.setOnClickListener(this);`, it will pass the view clicked (your button) into  `public void onClick(View v) {`, therefore the `View v` will be the button. You can use `getAdapterPosition()` insode that `onClick` to know the position

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Is it possible to get the position value of the currently clicked item in onClick (View v) and compare it with if to btnItemButton.setTextColor?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko 
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(onItemClickListener != null)
            {
                onItemClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
            }
            
            switch(getAdapterPosition())
            {
                default:
                    btnItemButton.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    break;
            }
        } 

This form?

Comment: `onClick` itself has nothing to do with the position, it just handles the click on the view.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko So where should we handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my understanding you need to change the text color based on button click?

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        SingleItem item = items.get(position);
        viewHolder.btnItemButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(position == 4) {
                    viewHolder.btnItemButton.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }else{
                    viewHolder.btnItemButton.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
            }
        });


        viewHolder.btnItemButton.setText(item.getmSubText());
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to define the public class SingleAdapter separately from mSingleAdapter.setOnItemClickListener elsewhere?